# Input group prepend text sizing incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Trying to add prepend text to a form field which is of size large however the prepend box and text is stuck at default size even after setting the input group to large.

```
<Form className="forms mx-auto" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <InputGroup className="input-group-lg" size="lg" className="my-4" >
        <InputGroup.Prepend>
            <InputGroup.Text>@</InputGroup.Text>
        </InputGroup.Prepend>
        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </InputGroup>
</Form>
```

It comes out like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z98WQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:
[image]

I suspect it has to do with your duplicate declaration of `className`, the second being to `my-4`. Either remove that of verify that that class does not mess with the layout.

Comment: already tried that, the first className declaration was just a fragment of messing around trying to fix it. I've tried with just size="lg" with nothing else and still not working for me

Comment: Then you almost certainly must have messed with the CSS class definitions used by bootstrap elsewhere. I literally copied and pasted your code and it worked. We need a reproducible example in order to help you.

Comment: Figured it out. I was manually linking to bootstrap css in index.html instead of using the module and I guess the linked one didn't have the correct classes.